# Using Codekit 2 with Susy and Breakpoint

Tags: susy-compass, compass-sass, codekit, breakpoint-sass

I like to use Codekit for a Compass-Poject with Susy and Breakpoint.

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/reset";
@import "susy";
@import "breakpoint";
```

But there is an error message "File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint."

Can i use Breakpoint with Codekit2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, however as Codekit 2 doesn't come bundled with Breakpoint like it does Susy and Compass, it's not as easy as `@import "breakpoint";`. What you will need to do is, using Codekit 2's [Bower](https://incident57.com/codekit/#bower) integration, download the `breakpoint-sass` bower package and change your import to `@import "../bower_components/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint";`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.
The path is "../bower_components/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint"

Answer (score 0):

Why not use @include susy-breakpoint(setting, layout);? It allows you to add settings once instead of using @include breakpoint(your setting); and then @include layout(your layout); on the next line.

Comment: I followed the recommendations from the Susy documentation:
"The only requirement is Sass, but Susy was built to be part of the Compass ecosystem, and we recommend pairing with tools like Breakpoint and Vertical Rhythms."

Answer (score 0):

I no longer see breakpoint-sass in the Codekit listing of bower packages. I will keep checking.

Answer (score 0):

For those cannot find **breakpoint-sass** in the CodeKit listing of bower packages, you can do the following.

```
npm install -g bower
bower install at-import/breakpoint
```

And then

```
@import "../bower_components/compass-breakpoint/stylesheets/breakpoint"
```

inside your main `.scss` file.